# Proof of an upper bound for $\sum_{i=c}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i^k}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality

Can someone prove or disprove the following statement for $k > 1$

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=c}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i^k} \leq \frac{1}{(k-1)c^{k-1}}
\end{align*}

Comment: My anwer is wrong ! I delete it. Use what TZakrevskiy answered and give him the credit ! Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{i=c}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i^k} \le \sum_{i\ge c}\int_{i-1}^{i}\frac{dx}{x^k}=\int_{c-1}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^k}=\frac{1}{(k-1)(c-1)^{k-1}}$$

Comment: Thanks! This proof is so simple but elegant

Comment: I was totally wrong !! I deleted my answer (see my comment to the OP). $+1$